# I always have this "character encoding of the HTML document was not declared " error

Tags: html, encoding

This is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="survey.manifest">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Offline Survey Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/survey.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/survey.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried putting the meta tag but I still have the same error.

Comment: What tool is giving you this error?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

instead of

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
```

?

Comment: Why would you expect the stray end tag to cause the start tag to be ignored?

Comment: Absolutely not sure in your case, but the single one works since years. I guess there is another utf-8 problem, in js or php header.

Comment: @Quentin Depends on the mysterious validator.